# Powershell: Can I add a role assignment without adding user to AAD?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to add external users to my subscription. Each user would get access to only one resource group, which is created for him.

From the portal, I can do it manually and it would recognize that the user is new and would get an email.
[image]

However, `New-AzRoleAssignment` gives me an error, saying that `The provided information does not map to an AD object id.`

Does Powershell allow to 'force' invite a user or I need to `New-AzureADMSInvitation` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invite the user to the AAD tenant first via the portal or `New-AzureADMSInvitation` as you mentioned first, `New-AzRoleAssignment` will not do that for you.